# Catching Errors while calling an API from a NgRx effect

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to catch an error on the effect of a specific action. Everything is working fine, whether when the call succeeds or fails. However, I think the code is very verbose, and could be improved on, specially:

- The catchError part, I'm returning `empty()` but I bieleve should be returning the `SavedReplyDeleteFailed` action. When doing so the whole effects breaks and does not compile, not sure on whats the best practice for handling this.
- I'm relying too much on the `tap` and `dispatch` instead of returning the actions from the map/mergeMap call backs. When I do so the effects compilation breaks as well.

How I can apply the above improvements?

```js
    deleteSavedReply = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteRequested),
        mergeMap( action => {
            this.store.dispatch( SavedRepliesActions.DeleteLoading({ isLoading: true }) );
            return this.savedRepliesService.deleteSavedReply(action.id).pipe(
                tap(res => {
                    this.store.dispatch( SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteSucess({ id: action.id }));
                    this.toastr.success( 'Saved Reply has been successfully deleted');
                }),
                catchError((error) => {
                    this.store.dispatch( SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteFailed({message: error.message}) );
                    this.toastr.error( error.message, 'Something went wrong');
                    this.store.dispatch( SavedRepliesActions.DeleteLoading({ isLoading: false }) );
                    return empty();
                })
            );
        }),
        map(() => {
            return SavedRepliesActions.DeleteLoading({ isLoading: false });
        }),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt for a more reactive way (using RxJS powerful), and so simplify a little your code with something like this:

```js
deleteSavedReply$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteRequested),
  mergeMap(action => this.savedRepliesService.deleteSavedReply(action.id).pipe(
    switchMap(res => [
      SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteSucess({ id: res.id }),
      UiActions.showToastrSuccess('Saved Reply has been successfully deleted')
    ]),
    catchError(error => of(
      SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteFailed({ message: error.message }),
      UiActions.showToastrError(error.message, 'Something went wrong')
    ]))
  ))
))
```

To do this, in the `redux` mindset, you should :

- Create 2 new actions `UiActions.showToastrSuccess` and `UiActions.showToastrError` to show a message Toastr. Displaying a message is a could target for an action.
- Use `reducer` to your `loading` flag. It's a slice of your state, so should change its value inside a reducer in place of the effect.

For example :

```js
on(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteFailed, (state) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: false
})),

on(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteRequested, (state) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: true
})),
```

#### Other option

Note that another option (or improvment...) could be to dispatch **Toastr** actions, inside `SavedReplyDeleteSucess` action. 
For example :

```js
deleteSavedReply$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteRequested),
  mergeMap(action => this.savedRepliesService.deleteSavedReply(action.id).pipe(
    map(res => SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteSucess({ id: res.id }))
    catchError(error => of(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteFailed({ message: error.message })))
  ))
))

savedReplyDeleteSucess$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteSucess),
  map(_ => UiActions.showToastrSuccess('Saved Reply has been successfully deleted'))
))

savedReplyDeleteFailed$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteFailed),
  map(message => UiActions.showToastrError(error.message, 'Something went wrong'))
))
```

The advantage here is that you can make your code evolving, by adding some extra effects in case of success or failure.
for example:

```js
savedReplyDeleteFailed$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedReplyDeleteFailed),
  switchMap(message => [
    UiActions.showToastrError(error.message, 'Something went wrong')),
    SystemActions.sendTraceError(error)
))
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: great stuff, and for UiActions.showToastSuccess this is another action with its own effect that actually fires the Toastr service right ?

Comment: Yes absolutely. It could be a separate store with reducers and effects shared globally with your application, where you can manage your UI. But it's just an example.